# Python webbrowser module?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the webbrowser module but it is not working for what I would like it to do.

```
    import webbrowser

    key="Yes"
    key1="yes"
    key2="No"
    key3="no"

    ques1=input("Would you like us to open a website for you?")
    if ques1 == key or key1:
        webbrowser.open("http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
    elif ques1 == key2 or key3:
        print("We will open a website for you automatically. http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
```

Comment: Try `if ques == key or ques1 == key1:`...

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, I do not like the newer versions of python, I prefer the older versions haha.

Comment: In both versions it's like that only bro :)

Comment: What would you like it to do and how is it now working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have typed the link in the print() module!
This code will work:

```
import webbrowser
key="Yes"
key1="yes"
key2="No"
key3="no"

ques1=input("Would you like us to open a website for you?")
if ques1 == key:
        webbrowser.open("http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
elif ques1 == key1:
        webbrowser.open("http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
if ques1 == key2:
        print("We will open a website for you automatically")
        webbrowser.open("https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
elif ques1 == key3:
         print("We will open a website for you automatically")
         webbrowser.open("https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-the-Blue-Screen-of-Death-on-Windows")
```

Comment: No, this won't work correctly since the `if`s are at fault.

Comment: That too. Forgot about that :)